# Remove a large file from GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a local repo to my private GitHub and got an error saying the file size exceeded 100MB. That I understand.  I actually don't need that file, so I deleted if from my repository (actually deleted it from my computer).

When I went to push the repository again (without that large file since it had been deleted) I get the same error for that file that was deleted from my computer.  I even added it to my gitignore file.

Not sure why that file is still causing an issues as it has been deleted from my computer.

Comment: Did you try running "git-clean"?

Comment: @woodlumhoodlum no, is that the command or is there more to it?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: the file is still included in your history. you will need to rewrite history to remove it. you can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1761499) or [this Github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

Answer (score 5):

Since you have committed your large file, it is currently in git history, and deleting it will not help - git keeps it should you ever want to rewind back to that commit.

What you need to do is to rewrite history. Easiest way to kill last commit is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

If this was not last commit, you may need to kill more, or use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch). You can find more about rewriting history in [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html).